# U-SQL script debugging error

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

While debugging the U-SQL script, I am facing the debug issue of ScopeEngine.
"ScopeEngine.pdb file contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ScopeEngine.dl"
[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Data Lake Tools are you using?

Comment: Version is 2.2.5000.0

Answer (score 0):

You should be safe to ignore ScopeEngine.pdb as it is not supposed to be debuggable in your case. It's a native DLL.

Comment: Hi Yu Dong, I didn't get the issue fixed in local machine Visual Studio. But tried executing the same piece of code in Azure VM. There it started debugging the code. I am still not sure what is the issue in my local environment

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't specify, I assume you are debugging a local run of your job in VS (rather than debugging a failed vertex). In this scenario you can see failure anywhere in the stack but the intent is to let you debug user code you wrote (UDFs, included assembly). There is a whole lot of runtime stack that you cannot debug in.

If you are seeing a failure inside the stack you should refer to the error message of course. If it says internal error you can raise a ticket with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

For your local machine, you can try to go to the VS debugging options and:

- Uncheck Enable just my code
- Check Suppress JIT optimization on module load